# Flash mobile development - How to detect Microphone availability using AIR 3.4?

Tags: android, mobile, air, microphone

I'm encountering an issue with AIR 3.4 and the new Kindle Fire (2nd gen, non-HD).
There is no microphone, as Amazon's comparison chart illustrates: https://developer.amazon.com/sdk/fire/specifications.html, but AIR is telling me that there is a microphone.
It also reports a value of TRUE for Camera.isSupported and CameraUI.isSupported.

So here's the scoop on Kindle Fire:

- 1st generation Kindle Fire does not properly support audio capture from within AIR (even with an external Microphone connected). For more information, see: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3197063
- 2nd generation Kindle Fire doesn't support audio capture unless an external microphone is connected. However, I don't know of a way within AIR to differentiate between headphone or no, because Microphone.isSupported always returns TRUE.
- Kindle Fire HD supports audio capture with or without an external mic.

The best metric I know of to handle this, so far, is to use "android.os.Build.MODEL" to disable microphone use for the 1st gen Kindle.
This is kind of clunky though.
It also doesn't allow me to properly handle the 2nd gen Fire because there is no way (that I know of) to determine if the user has a microphone plugged in.

Do any of you know a more reliable way to check for this?

**Edit**: Here's a test project that I've created that illustrates the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" applicationComplete="init()"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160">
    
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private function init():void {
                cameraLabel.text = "Camera: " + Camera.isSupported.toString();
                cameraUILabel.text = "CameraUI: " + CameraUI.isSupported.toString();
                microphoneLabel.text = "Microphone: " + Microphone.isSupported.toString() + " => " + Microphone.getMicrophone();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    
    <s:VGroup horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
        <s:Label id="cameraLabel" />
        <s:Label id="cameraUILabel" />
        <s:Label id="microphoneLabel" />
    </s:VGroup>
    
</s:Application>
```

Running this program on a 2nd gen Kindle Fire results in the following values being displayed on the screen:

> Camera: true
>
> CameraUI: true
>
> Microphone: true => [object Microphone]

Comment: What happens if you do `Microphone.getMicrophone()` on a device where it's not actually supported? I would imagine you get `null` back. That might be the best test in this scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately, Microphone.getMicrophone() returns a Microphone object. (Also, you have to be extra careful when and where you invoke Microphone.getMicrophone(). It's a static method, and unfortunately, calling it twice disconnects/orphans the Microphone object returned from the first invocation. I try to avoid using it anywhere but where necessary.)

Comment: I've added a test application (to my initial post) that shows you what I've tried and the results I'm getting.

Comment: What do you get if you do `adb shell ls /dev/snd/` ? Is there any device named `pcmCxDyc` (where x and y are digits; typically you're interested in pcmC0D0c)? That would be the PCM capture device.

Comment: Ah. There are:

`$ adb shell ls /dev/snd/
controlC0
pcmC0D0p
pcmC0D1c
pcmC0D1p
pcmC0D2c
pcmC0D3c
pcmC0D3p
pcmC0D4c
pcmC0D4p
pcmC0D5c
pcmC0D5p
timer`